# Write data to existing XML using PowerShell

Tags: xml, powershell

I have an XML doc that I need to write some data into a specific tag. I have an array of data and I need each index of the array to go to its own DETAILS tag. What I have below will write the entire array into each detail tag. how it ends up looking is DETAILS 1111 2222 3333 /DETAILS in each of the tags. Any help to even get me started or put me down the right path is appreciated.

```
Example 1
[xml]$xmldoc = Get-Content -Path 'C:\temp\myXML.xml'
$xmlFindingDetails = $xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("DETAILS")
$test = @("1111", "22222", "33333")
$count = 0
foreach ($one in $xmlFindingDetails){
    $one.InnerText[$count] = $test[$count]
    $count++
}

$xmldoc.Save('C:\temp\myXML.xml')
```

```
Example 2
[xml]$xmldoc = Get-Content -Path 'C:\temp\myXML.xml'
$xmlDetails = $xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("DETAILS")
$test = @("1111", "2222", "3333")
foreach ($one in $xmlDetails){
    $one.InnerText = $test
}

$xmldoc.Save('C:\temp\myXML.xml')
```

```
Before:
<TEST>
  <PRODUCT>
    <DETAILS></DETAILS>
  </PRODUCT>
</TEST>
<TEST>
  <PRODUCT>
    <DETAILS></DETAILS>
  </PRODUCT>
</TEST>
<TEST>
  <PRODUCT>
    <DETAILS></DETAILS>
  </PRODUCT>
</TEST>
```

```
How I need it to look:
<TEST>
  <PRODUCT>
    <DETAILS>1111</DETAILS>
  </PRODUCT>
</TEST>
<TEST>
  <PRODUCT>
    <DETAILS>2222</DETAILS>
  </PRODUCT>
</TEST>
<TEST>
  <PRODUCT>
    <DETAILS>3333</DETAILS>
  </PRODUCT>
</TEST>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
$i=0;@("1111","2222","3333")|%{
  $xmlDoc.TEST[($i)].PRODUCT.innerText = "$($_)";$i++
}
```

Iterate over the multiple TEST tags using arrays

Comment: Now say under PRODUCT there is more than just details. Say, DETAILS, ACCOUNT, SIZE. How would I pick just detail with your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach.

```
$xmlDetails = $xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("DETAILS")
$test = "1111", "2222", "3333"

0..($xmlDetails.Count - 1) | ForEach-Object {
    $xmlDetails[$_].InnerText = $test[$_]
}
```

You could use the counts to ensure there are the same number of details slots as there are values

```
if($xmlDetails.count -eq $test.count)
{
    $xmlDetails = $xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("DETAILS")
    $test = "1111", "2222", "3333"

    0..($xmlDetails.Count - 1) | ForEach-Object {
        $xmlDetails[$_].InnerText = $test[$_]
    }
}
```